# What will be the maple code to find the values of the exponents of the given function?

Tags: maple

I have a mathematical expression of the form

$$f(m)=A-B*\left(\frac{m+1}{\psi}+\frac{K1*(1-\beta^{m+1})+K2*\alpha^{m-1}}{K3*\alpha^{m-1}}\right),$$ where $A,B,\psi,K1,K2,K3,\alpha,\beta$ are constants. Fixing the parameters, I want to find the values of $m$ with the variation of a particular constant, for which the $f(m)=0$ or $\approx 0$. `What will be the maple code for this problem?`

Comment: Exactly what you said it to be: Fix the values of the needed constants ("psi:=31; A:=10; B=...;"), setup the equation as "f:=0;" with the full expression as given above and then call "fsolve(f=0,m);".

Comment: @Yiannis Galidakis With `fsolve` I got the result.

Comment: If my function will be little changed to $$f(m)=A-B*\left(\frac{m+1}{\psi}+\frac{K1*(1-\beta^{m+1})+K2*\alpha^{m-1}}{K3* \alpha^{m-1}+u[m]}\right),$$ where $u[n] $ is a sequence. Then `fsolve` is not working. What will be the change in this case?

Comment: fsolve may not be able to help you in that case, unless you have an explicit form for $u[m]$, in terms of $m$. Any such $u[m]$ is essentially a new dependent variable $g(m)$ and you already have one such variable $f(m)$ on the left side of the equation.